# javascript change speed of a ball in a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a ball bouncing in a canvas and I am trying to change the speed the ball travels at and I'm not getting it to work. I'm trying to implement the speed just as I am doing the ball color and ball width but its not working. setInterval in the code is what alters the speed but cant get it to take the value form the speedx input.

javascript:

```
function draw(){
 var canvas = document.getElementById('ball');
 context = ball.getContext('2d');
 //context.clearRect(150,50,750,750);
 context.beginPath();
 context.fillStyle="#0000ff";
 context.arc(x,y,10,20,Math.PI*2,true);
  context.closePath();
  lineColor = document.getElementById('lineColor').value;
  lineWidth = document.getElementById('lineWidth').value;
    speed = document.getElementById('speedx').value;
        setInterval(draw,speed); 

        if (lineWidth)
        {
            context.lineWidth=lineWidth;
        }
        if (lineColor)
        {
            context.strokeStyle=lineColor;
            context.stroke();
        }
}
```

HTML:

```
      Ball Width: <input type="text" id="lineWidth"></input>
Ball Color: <input type="text" id="lineColor"></input>
Ball Speed X:<input type="text" id="speedx"></input>
```

Comment: Could you add some comments in here and maybe point out the exact line that is not working as intended.

Comment: Does "draw" execute the first time?  I'm thinking what probably happens is that it starts off as empty string, so the setTimeout doesn't get called again, so it doesn't loop.  Perhaps a check to see if "speed" is empty, and if so, set it to some default?

Comment: duplicate by OP (answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11846038/html-javascript-canvas-change-set-value-to-a-user-input)

Answer (score 1):

It appears as though you are setting a thousand timers without ever stopping the previous ones because you are using setInterval instead of setTimeout. This basically creates a new timer each time draw is called, and draw is called each time each timer has an interval. I would assume this makes it run at the fastest speed possible at all times.

Also, from this code it is not clear where x and y are set.

Also, finding the context each iteration is not optimal performance wise.